# Problems with iSCSI timing out on write operations

Tags: hard-drive, raid

I am running on 14.04.1 with `iscsid` version 2.0-873

I have an Enhance Ultrastor E3160 that is formatted raid5 on the backend and formatted as EXT4 on my system.  I can see the device, attach it, mount it, and write small files (<300MB), but when writing larger files we see repeated `connection3:0: detected conn error (1020)`. Eventually, we see this sequence of events in dmesg:

```
[ 1905.583015] sd 13:0:0:0: [sde] Medium access timeout failure. Offlining disk!
[ 1905.583018] sd 13:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[ 1905.583024] sd 13:0:0:0: [sde] Unhandled error code
[ 1905.583027] sd 13:0:0:0: [sde]
[ 1905.583029] Result: hostbyte=DID_TIME_OUT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[ 1905.583031] sd 13:0:0:0: [sde] CDB:
[ 1905.583032] Write(16): 8a 00 00 00 00 00 a7 ef 84 00 00 00 04 00 00 00
[ 1905.583040] end_request: I/O error, dev sde, sector 2817491968
[ 1905.583117] EXT4-fs warning (device sde): ext4_end_bio:317: I/O error -5 writing to inode 43 (offset 3607101440 size 8175616 starting block 352186624)
```

We have four other/older UltraStor raids attached via private subnets that work just fine.  This device is on a public net, and located in a different machine room.

I am working with our hardware vendor, but thought I'd ask the Ubuntu community for any insights or other things to test.

Comment: I would use the disks utility to check the SMART data and verify the physical consistency of the disk. UDMA errors, IO problems, and others could easily be the cause of the described behaviour. I/O error -5  ********************** After that, you may just have a failed inode. if the hardware is fine, you can recover inodes & superblocks easily. http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/surviving-a-linux-filesystem-failures.html Check the condition of your hard disk drives first.

Comment: disks utility?  My hardware is not supported by smartctl so not sure how to check health of my media.  The backend system is not reporting any errors.   When I add the iscsi node, the first fsck fixes the journal, but there are no other errors reported on that fsck or fsck -f.  Anything else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

There are three more things you can do:

- Check the SCSI terminator and replace that. (hardware, to be taken up with your vendor)
- Check the device(s) with `badblocks` in another enclosure
- Use commercial software (the only non-free software I still possess) to check (and maybe repair) your disk.  But before we go there, I'd like you to check the two previous items.

Comment: Drop me a note here @Fabby if the first two don't give you the required effect.